# Application not respond to sendmessage mouse events

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, sendmessage

I try emulate clicks on a exe application programatically with sendmessage from my own app , but not work.
I need just from my software send a click to third party app running.

Is as very strange situation, and sendmassage is the way to go for me, duet need sent mouse events to that application when mouse is used in other applications on foreground etc.

Spy++ show this
When I click the desired object with my mouse:

<001454> 00000000000C058E S WM_NCHITTEST xPos:21 yPos:143

<001455> 00000000000C058E R WM_NCHITTEST nHittest:HTCLIENT

<001456> 00000000000C058E S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000C058E nHittest:HTCLIENT wMouseMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN

<001457> 00000000000C058E R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:True

<001458> 00000000000C058E P WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:21 yPos:120

<001459> 00000000000C058E P WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:21 yPos:120

<001460> 00000000000C058E S WM_CAPTURECHANGED hwndNewCapture:00000000

<001461> 00000000000C058E R WM_CAPTURECHANGED

Using sendmssage not work.

```
int X = 23;
int Y = 115
var w = (Y << 16) | X;
SendMessage(windowHandle, Win32.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0x0001, w);
SendMessage(windowHandle, Win32.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0x0000, w);
```

Messages form spy++ show messages arrive when I send with sendmessage but the button not respond:

<000009> 00000000000C058E S WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:23 yPos:115

<000010> 00000000000C058E S WM_CAPTURECHANGED hwndNewCapture:000C058E

<000011> 00000000000C058E R WM_CAPTURECHANGED

<000012> 00000000000C058E R WM_LBUTTONDOWN

<000013> 00000000000C058E S WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:23 yPos:115

<000014> 00000000000C058E S WM_CAPTURECHANGED hwndNewCapture:00000000

<000015> 00000000000C058E R WM_CAPTURECHANGED

<000016> 00000000000C058E R WM_LBUTTONUP

What i miss here?
Is related to WM_SETCURSOR?

---

My code here with real values, anyway the spy++ show the messages are ok on the spy aplication:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam)

    IntPtr windowHandle;



     Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Rack");

        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
         windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;



        }

     int X = 23;
     int Y = 115;
     var w = (Y << 16) | X;
     int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
     int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
     SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0x0001, w);
     SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0x0000, w);
```

Using potsmessages, this is what SPY++ show.
I sent firts mouse move.

```
        PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0x0001, w);
        PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0x0001, w);
        PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0x0000, w);
```

<000001> 000000000033041A P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:23 yPos:115

<000002> 000000000033041A P WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:23 yPos:115

<000003> 000000000033041A P WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:23 yPos:115

<000004> 000000000033041A S WM_CAPTURECHANGED hwndNewCapture:00000000

<000005> 000000000033041A R WM_CAPTURECHANGED

<000006> 000000000033041A P WM_MOUSELEAVE

Comment: Show me your `SendMessage(...)` and the rest of related code.

Comment: Hi, check again I update with code with real parameters.

Comment: Basic differences are that you did not send WM_MOUSEMOVE so don't get the hit test and cursor messages and you used SendMessage but these messages are normally posted (P vs S in the Spy++ trace), so use PostMessage instead.  The SendMessage declaration is wrong, visit the pinvoke.net web site for better declarations.

Comment: Thanks fore the repply.


Already test with WM_MOUSEMOVE , sending mouse move before send WM_LBUTTONDOWN   nothing happen.

The declaration of sendmessage is correct, not is mandatory int wParam, int lParam be  intptr if you know what you are doing.
If the delcaration is incoprrect thenm the sendmessages are incorrect and for sure if you check the log spy++, the declaration is correct.

Why you said is incorrect?

Comment: Postmessage no is a option here duet the application cant gain focus.
WIth postmesages need the app receive the postmesages on focus , right?

Comment: OK, im wrong postmesage is a option and work in extreme very similar way than sendmessage.

Testing now with postmesage, buton continue without work.

This is what SPY++  show with potsmesage, check, updated the question with this info.